# How do I indent properly with TextMate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate, indentation

I'm reading Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorials. I just came across my first example of code (HTML really) being long enough to wrap to a second line. Here's what it looks like in my TextMate...

[image: My TextMate]

The lines between the paragraph tags aren't lined up below the "a href" (as I'm thinking they should be).

Now here is the same code taken from Michael's tutorial...

[image]

In Michael's example the same lines are perfectly lined up under the "a href".

How can I properly indent my code in TextMate to look as neat as Michael's does here?

Thanks!

Eddie

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to View and turn softwrap off, then put linebreaks and tabs in manually.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Text>Reformat Paragraph menu command (Ctrl-Q).

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, [there's a six year old request](http://ticket.macromates.com/show?ticket_id=4EFB31A8) to add this sort of smart indenting to TextMate.